# Rewrite in apache server

Tags: apache, url-rewriting

I've got the following in my httpaccess file on my apache http server.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]
RewriteRule ^((?!web).*)$ /web/$1 [NC,L]
```

and it's working properly. But i wan to apply this condition for all urls except when I ask for `/correoimages/` then I want that the url be the same url that is requested. How can I do that?

That is when I ask for `https://example.org/CORREOIMAGES/a.jpg` the url must be `https:///example.org/correoimages/a.jpg` and not `https://example.org/web/correoimages/a.jpg`. In the rest of the case web must be added.

I dont´understand properly `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond`.

Comment: Hi, please format your code using the visual editor or markdown syntax. Docs [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an exception to your rule set:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /web/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^correoimages/ - [L]

RewriteRule ^((?!web).*)$ /web/$1 [NC,L]
```